# Using react-spring useSprings with dynamic items array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik, react-spring

I am attempting to use react-spring's `useSprings` to enable users to reorder the items in a formik `FieldArray`. The useSprings Draggable List demo ([found here](https://codesandbox.io/s/r5qmj8m6lq?from-embed)) uses `useRef` to manage the order of items. `FieldArray` comes with a number of array helper functions for inserting, removing, and moving items.

The issues that I'm having are:

1) Re-ordering existing items using formik's `move` array helper method successfully changes the array order, but requires an additional click to render the correct order

2) Adding or removing array items using array helper methods produces unexpected results. Mutating the length of the ref doesn't change the length of `order.current` inside of `useGesture`

I've also tried using `useState` instead of `useRef` and updating the state with `useEffect` when props change.

Here is a code sandbox I made: https://codesandbox.io/s/usesprings-with-fieldarray-56bex

In the `bind` function, commenting out

```
order.current = newOrder;
```

and uncommenting

```
// arrayHelpers.move(currIndex, currRow);
```

shows issue #1 that I mentioned above.

I would like to be able to use formik's `move`, `insert`, and `remove` helper functions with react-spring to seamlessly re-order, add, and delete items within a `FieldArray`.

Comment: Hey! Did you managed to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can try setting the new order.current after adding the new element

```
  onClick={() =>{
          arrayHelpers.insert(items.length, {
            name: `Item ${items.length + 1}`
          })
          order.current = [...order.current, order.current.length];
        }
      }
```

this will add the new item at the end of the list.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered at least your #1 issue.

Note that the the `setSprings` function doesn't re-render anything on its own, and the `useSprings` is missing a `dependencies` array to auto-update.

`react-springs@9.0.0.beta-23` has a dependencies array, and together with the `useSpringsFixed` wrapper in the sandbox that is linked [here](https://github.com/react-spring/react-spring/issues/714) it should force-rerender on changed props.

Hope that helps your issue too.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm now following the issue you opened on Github.